# React Navigation v6: How do you pass arbitrary props to Tab Navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6, react-native-tabnavigator

I have the following Tab Navigator in my React Native app, using React Navigation v6:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1}/>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen2}/>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I want to pass a prop called `prop1` that will be accessible in each screen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by moving the component from the `component` prop to become a child of the screen.  Example:

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen1">
    {() => <Screen1 prop1={prop1} />}
  </Tab.Screen>
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen2">
    {() => <Screen2 prop1={prop1} />}
  </Tab.Screen>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

[Official doc here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#children)